# Where does Madrox the Multiple Man store all of his duplicates?

Tags: marvel, x-men

[Jamie Madrox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamie_Madrox), also known as Multiple Man, is a mutant starring in Marvel Comics' [*X-Factor*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Factor_%28comics%29). Madrox can, upon receiving a physical impact, create duplicates of himself. Like this:

[image]

[image]

Wikipedia goes into [great detail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamie_Madrox#Powers_and_abilities) about Multiple Man's powers, but doesn't seem to address where they are stored when not active. Are they grown instantaneously from a single cell? And if that's so, how do the same dupes get regrown over and over again (it's been shown that some of his dupes have more assertive personalities and freewill, and have appeared multiple times).

When his dupes aren't walking around on Earth, where are they?

Comment: Probably some kind of quantum effect. But I can't come up with anything real good right now.

Comment: Drawing them from the multiverse?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jamie Madrox's powers create duplicates of himself.  The duplicates are created instantaneously when he is struck, so no storage space is required.

Each duplicate expresses different parts of his psyche, an effect he has no control over.  It's certainly possible that a duplicate left alone for long enough to begin gaining some independent personality could resurface after being reabsorbed - when Madrox absorbs his clones, he gains the knowledge they had.  Any duplicate which received largely the same parts of his mind as the previous clone had had would act in much the same way.

Comment: As backup, the Marvel Wikipedia has a bit more detail, although it's speculation: "Jamie Madrox creates an identical physical living duplicate of himself upon any physical impact, possibly via extra-dimensional mass acquisition similar to the process used by Ant-Man or the Hulk." http://marvel.wikia.com/James_Madrox_%28Earth-616%29

Comment: so? If he absorbs his duplicate he gain the knowledge gained by that dupe? Can that dupe be destroyed in anyway? incineration/

Comment: So, if he can create dupe and absorb the dupes knowledge. what happens if the dupe get killed? will he absorb the damage as well? Oh, can he get damaged, get hurt?

Comment: The impacts hurt him, I believe, just as they should.  His duplicates can be killed (and often are) and he doesn't absorb their knowledge if it happens.  He also doesn't suffer any ill effect if his duplicates are injured or killed.